# Angular 4/5 Observable - How to update component template depending on observable property?

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, observable, single-page-application

Ok I am still a newbie. I have successfully created a 'dashboard' component that has a left sidebar with links. On the right is where I have content/components displayed that I want to change dynamically depending on what link was clicked on the left sidebar (see bootstrap sample of what this dashboard looks like here, click on the toggle button to view the sidebar: https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/).

I have created a DashboardService that has a Subject and an Observable to allow for sibling component communication. This works great since I have a console.log() that shows this communication working (when I click on link on sidebar in SidebarComponent, I console.log() a value 'emitted' by the DashboardService that is being listened to by the SidebarComponent's sibling, DashboardSectionComponent).

The problem that I am having is that the template in DashboardSectionComponent loads the correct component section ONLY on initial load of page - once I click on a link on the side bar the content is blank and nothing is rendered.

Here is the service that allows the componenent communication:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class DashboardService {

    private selectedComponentAlias = new Subject<string>();

    constructor() {}

    setSelectedComponentAlias(alias: string) {
        this.selectedComponentAlias.next(alias);
    }

    getSelectedComponentAlias(): Observable<string> {
        return this.selectedComponentAlias.asObservable();
    }

}
```

Here is the SidebarComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { DashboardService } from '../dashboard.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-sidebar',
    templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    onShowSection(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const componentAlias = event.target.getAttribute('data-componentAlias');
        this.dashboardService.setSelectedComponentAlias(componentAlias);
    }

}
```

here is the DashboardSectionComponent (the one that subscribes to the observable and I want to set property that controls the template views depending on the value that was caught)

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { DashboardService } from '../dashboard.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard-section',
    templateUrl: './dashboard-section.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard-section.component.css']
})
export class DashboardSectionComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    private subscrition: Subscription;
    selectedComponentAlias: string = 'user-profile';

    constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscrition = this.dashboardService.getSelectedComponentAlias()
            .subscribe((selectedComponentAlias: string) => {
                this.selectedComponentAlias = selectedComponentAlias;
                console.log('user clicked: ',this.selectedComponentAlias);
            });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscrition.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

Finally here is the template for DashboardSectionComponent which might have wrong syntax:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedComponentAlias == 'my-cards'">
    <app-cards></app-cards>
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedComponentAlias == 'user-profile'">
    <app-user-profile></app-user-profile>
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedComponentAlias == 'user-settings'">
    <app-user-settings></app-user-settings>
</div>
```

Again, this works great (selectedComponentAlias is 'user-profile' on page load by default). But it goes blank after I click on a Sidebar link....

Thanks.

Comment: I really hate to be the bearer of bad news, but your approach is a bit off. You can make this work, and it won't be too hard, but your approach won't scale well. Looking only at the content section on the right, you have the need of three independent components (my-cards, user-profile, user-settings). You should investigate the use of routing and `<router-outlet>` to solve this problem appropriately.

Comment: I agree with @RandyCasburn. Also, just a tip about observables and Angular - instead of holding `selectedComponentAlias` (or any other value emitted from an Observable for that matter) in your component, I would use the `async` pipe and let Angular deal with the subscription instead.

Comment: what is the output of, console.log('user clicked: ',this.selectedComponentAlias); ?

Comment: @Luillyfe the correct string is shown in the log.

Comment: @RandyCasburn can you please provide more input? I'm new to this - I have routes in place - however can you explain what is wrong with having those three independent components? For example I plan to reuse the my-cards component elsewhere....

Comment: @AmitB. can you please point me to an example?

Comment: @PippyLongstocking - Hey Puppy - Have you actually completed the Angular tutorial? It is a great learning tool and may provide you with the insight you need. I don't think we'll be successful in this mode of communication. I believe the terminology may hamper things. I recommend you work through the tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

this was easy - like @RandyCasburn pointed out, this was a matter of getting the routing working properly.